# Codeigniter captcha image doesn't show all the characters when I change font

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha, helper

Using the default font, which is very small and pixelated, the captcha image shows all the characters. But if I use a custom font, the captcha code doesn't always show all the characters, although it seems to have enough space. The first character is sometimes shown close to the horizontal middle of the image, and because of that not all the characters are shown. Is there another way, other than that of increasing the image's width?

Comment: Does your new font actually have all required letters, digits and so on? Have you noticed if a certain letter behaves a certai way? Maybe you can have it as a background and use `background-position` if it's a position problem?

Comment: It has all the letters and digits, but because of the huge left padding it makes, not all the characters are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Not really much of an answer, but I ran across this a long time ago: [codeigniter/captcha helper/image sometimes pads too much on left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146582/codeigniter-captcha-helper-image-sometimes-pads-too-much-on-left)

Comment: so there is no other solution than making the captcha image with a bigger width... which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Perhaps just drop in your own Captcha library; CI is good at supply a basic version of most things you need, but they do tend to be rather basic